# Different buttons in same jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a button #create-user that opens a dialog with 2 buttons(submit, cancel). Is it possible to add another button #edit-user on the page that opens the same dialog but with different buttons (edit, delete, cancel)? This is my code so far:

```
$(function () {
var dialog, form,
        name = $("#name"),
        birthdate = $("#student-datepicker"),
        allFields = $([]).add(name).add(birthdate),
        tips = $(".validateTips");

    function addStudent() {
    var data = {
        'action': 'add_student',
        'name': name.val(),
        'birth': birthdate.val(),
        'add-student': true
    };



    var valid = false;
    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

    if (valid) {
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (studentId) {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        });

    } else {

    }
}

dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    show: {effect: "fade", duration: 200},
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": addStudent,
        ,
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addStudent();
});

$("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Acctually i solved it differently ...here is the solution and the code I added:

```
$(function(){
dialog2= $(".dialog-form").dialog({
    show: {effect: "fade", duration: 200},
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,

});

$(".edit-student").button().on("click", function () {
    dialog2.dialog(
                    'option',
                    'buttons', [{
                    text: 'A brand new button!',
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }]);
    dialog2.dialog("open");
    return false;
});});
```

I'm returning false on the button click event just to make sure the page isn't posting/refreshing.